# Autowired property giving null even though it instantiates in another controller

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security

I defined a CustomUserDetailsService that uses an autowired Account to pull the usernames from a Hibernate database. After trying to visit `http://localhost:8084/article`, which redirects to a Spring Security login page, I tried to log in using valid credentials. Here's the error I got:

> Your login attempt was not successful, try again.
>
> Reason: null

After a bit of debugging, I realized that AccountDao was never actually instantiated and it's null. On the other hand, this works fine in Spring MVC's ArticleAccount I defined (see `http://localhost:8084/article/add`). Why could it be?

Since the test case is quite big, here's the URL:
https://bitbucket.org/d33tah/javazaur/src/4e5451b

Comment: tl;dr. does your component-scan scans both classes?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/d33tah/javazaur/src/57ab759052846a42578bdc38012c61350dfeeb94/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml?at=master

Comment: How are you instantiating the object that has the null DAO reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration isn't shared between spring-security.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml. This means that your declaration of <context:component-scan> in dispatcher-servlet.xml is not applied to beans declared in spring-security.xml, including your `CustomUserDetailsService` bean.

Adding the following to the spring-security.xml should make the auto-wiring work:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="pl.javazaur" />
```

Comment: I changed that in commit 4e5451b, it still doesn't instantiate the Dao class.

Comment: The commit you made makes the change in dispatcher-servlet.xml, I'm instructing you to add this configuration to spring-security.xml. Of course you also need to update the beans element to include the "context" namespace. And you will most likely need to add any beans your bean depends on with auto-wiring.

Comment: Ah! I see. I tried something like that - it causes an error: `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory pl.javazaur.dao.ArticleDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Comment: And copying the SessionFactory-related XML entries from dispatcher gives: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun May 18 19:16:39 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy`

Comment: You should move all beans, which are not-related to MVC from dispatcher-servlet.xml to applicationContext.xml. Your dispatcher-servlet should only contain the InternalResourceViewResolver bean, tx:annotation-driven and context:component-scan. The reason is that content of dispatcher-servlet.xml IS NOT available in spring-security.xml. Also, you need to change your web.xml so that the contextConfigLocation is defined only once, with value "/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml, /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml".

Comment: You can read more on application context hierarchies for Spring MVC in http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet

Comment: Thanks! Now I've got the error `No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here`, but this feels outside of the scope of the question (I'd be happy to hear a hint anyway though ;))

Comment: ...nevermind, I was missing `<tx:annotation-driven/>` in spring-security.xml.

Answer (score 1):

These are your component-scan tags.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="pl.javazaur.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="pl.javazaur.pojo" />
<context:component-scan base-package="pl.javazaur.controller" />
```

And this is your CustomUserDetailsService package.

```
pl.javazaur.CustomUserDetailsService
```

So CustomUserDetailsService is out of scaned packages. 
Solution: use this component-scan

```
<context:component-scan base-package="pl.javazaur" />
```

Comment: (comment removed, see comments to vschafer's answer)